# for loops with nested if loop in java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, nested

Very new to Java, I am in an intro class in college and doing a project. I am trying to make a method that searches a String array for an inputted state and returns the index. If the user enters a query that is not in the array, I would like it to ask for a new state to search. 
My exception is saying "variable statePosition may not have been initialized."
Below is the code.

Thank you in advance!

```
static final int NUM_STATES = 50;

public static int askState(String[] stateNames) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String state;
    int statePosition;
    System.out.println("Please enter a state that you would like to search:");
    state = keyboard.next();
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
            if (state.equals(stateNames[i])) {
                statePosition = i;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid state:");
            }
            state = keyboard.next();
        }
        return statePosition;
    }
```

Comment: Initalialize the variable statePosition. 0 would work just fine.

Comment: String state= null;
    int statePosition=-1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use

```
 int statePosition = -1;
```

That would return -1 if it's not found. The error means you didn't assign a value to statePosition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize your variable `int statePosition;` like this:

```
int statePosition =-1;
```

Also initialize your `String state;` like this:

```
String state = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the exception states, you have to initialize the int statePosition:

```
int statePosition = null;
```

or

```
int statePosition = 0;
```

... you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize both variables

```
String state= null;
int statePosition=-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you never instantiate the statePosition variable but you are always returning it.

Try give statePosition a value (like others said -1).

Also try to do this with a while (instead of a for statement) which breaks if your statePosition was found.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is prone to encounter an error in one of it variables prior to their use further in the code.
I would suggest that every time you code, you should put the variables to initial state rather than leaving them with  a null value.

```
String state= null;
int statePosition=-1;
```

Put this in the code to have your problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change from using **int** to **Integer**. Integer is an object so it can be null. This way you can check to see if it has been set before performing any further actions.

```
static final int NUM_STATES = 50;

public static Integer askState(String[] stateNames) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String state;
    Integer statePosition;
    System.out.println("Please enter a state that you would like to search:");
    state = keyboard.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
        if (state.equals(stateNames[i])) {
            statePosition = i;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid state:");
        }
        state = keyboard.next();
    }
    if (statePosition == null) {
        throw new Exception("State Position Not Set :(");
    }
    return statePosition;
}
```